# User specific variables in Angular 2

Tags: angular, web-services, typescript

I am new to Angular and I have been reading around but still cannot find a proper way to handle user specific variables (let's say username) in a proper way. This is, that these variables can be accessed and edited by any component (I am trying to avoid global variables since I do not think they are appropriate for this concrete case)

Comment: You can use a service and inject it in any component you want.

Comment: variables are bound to your component/module scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use browser local storage to store userspecific data like 
 username/Userprofile/authtoken etc

```
let userProfile = {username: 'abc', ...};
localStorage.setItem('UserLocalProfile', userProfile);
```

you can remove it as well

```
localStorage.removeItem('UserLocalProfile');
```

You probable would write service and inject to Angular component for this purpose would better suite your need.

Here the example to get started..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TokenService {
    constructor() { }

    private storageName: string = "UserLocalStorage";

    setToken(token: string) {
        localStorage.setItem(this.storageName, token);
    }

    getToken() {
        let token = localStorage.getItem(this.storageName);
        return token;
    }

    clearToken() {
        localStorage.removeItem(this.storageName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you. I was using a service before but without relying in the local storage. It is a valid solution though I think it is not the perfect one.

But after setting the token, the storageName that appears in my browser is "undefined"! Why is this happening?

Comment: IMHO it is the common solution, Without looking your code, I can't explain why you get undefined, its just something wrong in your code only.